What episode of the Madeline Cartoon Series was Madeline sent to hospital?
I used to watch the cartoon series of Madeline faithfully when I was a child. While my memories of it wane and I only remember small snippets (ie. the girls referring to Pepito and his younger cousins as Bat Hats) there's one episode which while foggy in my memories, whenever I think of the show is the first episode I recall and I'd like to know exactly which episode it was.
I recall the episode having Miss Clavel singing that "Something Is Not Right" song where she wakes from her bed and quickly rushes to where the girls sleep during the night. When she gets there the girls are all out of bed and gathered together but they step way showing madeline is crying and seemingly in pain and is taken away by a doctor.
While Madeline are gone the other girls are still awake and at some point hear that Madeline is in hospital believing she has a hole in her and start imagining Madeline with a hole in various parts of her body.

one girl imagines Madeline with a empty circle in the middle of her body
another girl imagines Madeline taking her hat off and part of the top of her head is gone (it's not a proper circle but you can tell it would have been if it was lower)
I believe another girl imagined similar as the 2nd point but the missing part was her arm

In all of them I think they imagine Madeline in her pajamas thus it looked strange for her to wear her yellow hat with the second point.
Later, I believe the following morning, the girls see Madeline in hospital and it's revealed that she had an operation (reason why the girls had imagined Madeline having a hole in her). I don't recall what the operation was for but I do recall Madeline showing off the scar to the other girls.
I watched it in Australia on ABC. While I can't pin down the year I saw it I would say it was around in the 1990's, possibly on or after 1996 as I don't recall watching it in my first home but that might be moot because my memories of it are muddled up but I do believe it was while I was in primary school which was from 1995-1996 to around 2000.

Surely when Madeline had her appendix removed? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lo472Cpxhw8

@Kitkat "The uploader has not made this video available in your country.". however the title is Madeline - Madeline Gets Her Appendix Removed - 106. is this is episode 106 or season 1 episode 6?

while i'm not one to complain about downvotes. i hope the downvoter didn't downvote because this because it's off-topic and i should have done my research because (at the moment of posting) the meta indicating these were off-topic was posted 4 hours ago and this was posted 5 hours before that. i just happen to have the worst timing
